# What compounds are produced when you heat CuO and sugar?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm wondering on what compounds are produced when you heat CuO and sugar?

Comment: Under what conditions? In solution or just heat the solids together?

Comment: Brown goo, then black goo. And no, it is not going to be much more specific than that.

Comment: Any own ideas? And a context?

Answer (score 3):

If there is enough copper oxide, all you obtain is metallic copper, $\ce{CO2}$ and water. This mixture ($\ce{CuO}$ + organic substance) was the standard way of analyzing any new organic substance in the $19$th century. The formula of the compound was derived from the weight of $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$ collected. This is is still a standard question to be solved in high school chemistry courses all over the world.

Comment: That is, if there is enough copper oxide _and if you heat well enough._

Comment: @ Ivan Neretin. OK. I have edited your comment.

Comment: Justus Liebig's (1803-1873) development of microanalysis: https://www.chemistryworld.com/opinion/classic-kit-liebigs-kaliapparat/3004924.article